# Attching a Behaviour to a dynamically created table in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, behavior

How do I programmatically attach a Doctrine Behaviour to a table dynamically created through `$conn->export->createTable('MyTable', $definition)`?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
$definition = array(
    'id' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'primary' => true,
        'autoincrement' => true
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'length' => 255
    )
);

$conn->export->createTable('MyTable', $definition) ;
```

At this point I would need to attach a doctrine typical behaviour like Timestampable or Versionable to the newly created 'MyTable' table. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Behaviors are attached to objects, not tables. In what context are you doing this? Do you want to attach behaviors to the models you are creating, or are you attaching behaviors to temporary tables that you are creating on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

With `createTable` you directly create the table in your database (it is just a nice wrapper to not write the SQL). This is a more low level function.

Behaviours are defined in your [models](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/introduction-to-models). You can think about them as some kind of hooks that come into play when you retrieve or store data via this model.

In your case, you don't even have a model. So long text short answer:

**No it is not possible.**

Comment: Well you can dynamically map entities [source](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/). Not sure if it's all that impossible. I'm researching this myself. I'll update if I find anything.